# Batch file to enter incremental destination filename for Imgburn Build mode DVD ripping

Tags: windows, batch-file

> I'm trying to streamline a process I use often. Basically, my workflow is to take a disc (with recorded footage) from a DVD recorder and put it in the computer and use Imgburn's build mode to create an ISO of the disc. There are usually multiple discs in the same series of whatever I'm recording, so I would name them Smith 1.iso, Smith 2.iso, etc.
>
> I'm pretty new to this type of stuff, but I've made a few simple batch files for simplifying file copying and such.
>
> I've got a simple string for opening Imgburn in build mode and entering the source and destination paths:

```
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\ImgBurn\imgburn.exe /mode build /src D:\VIDEO_TS /dest C:\Video\Smith 1.iso
```

> I've found examples for batch files that create incremental names, but I don't know enough of how they work to know what to change to adapt for my needs.
>
> I would like for the batch file to check to see if Smith 1.iso exists and to enter in an incremental name such as Smith 2.iso, Smith 3.iso, and so forth in the /dest field. The highest number of discs in a series that I would ever need would probably be about 8.
>
> My ideal result would be for me to insert a disc, have an autorun.inf or something open a text box to prompt me for the initial file name. I'd enter Smith and it would create the names from there. Maybe it could keep that name as its label for that day and prompt me again the next day for a new name.
>
> Any help would be greatly appreciated!
>
> --James

UPDATE: This is where I'm at now:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%"
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
rem my testing command pushd "D:\bat\StackOverflow\files"
pushd "C:\Video\video depo %datestamp%"
if "%~1"=="" (
for /F ... %%u ... do set "baseName=%%~u"
  set /p "baseName=Enter Name, (Enter for default %baseName%): "
) else (
  set "baseName=%~1"
)
rem add a trailing space to basename end (optional)
set "baseName=%baseName% "
rem my testing command set "Extn=txt"
set "Extn=iso"
set /A "n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('
  2^>nul dir /b /a-d "%baseName%*.%Extn%"^
   ^|findstr /xri /c:"%baseName%[0-9]*.*"
') do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
  if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /a n+=1
set  "newName=%baseName%%n%.%Extn%"
echo %newName%
rem my testing command type nul>"%newName%"
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\ImgBurn\imgburn.exe /mode build /src D:\VIDEO_TS /dest C:\Video\video depo %datestamp%\%newName%
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2500 >NUL
start C:\imgburn.ahk
popd
endlocal
echo %baseName%>lastbaseName.txt
```

Comment: Did you a Google search for _increment file names in windows batch_? A bunch of hints... And a way to prompt an user for a text input? Type `set /?` in a command line window and pay your attention to  `/P` switch

Comment: I tried to insert code in my comment, but it wasn't working. I did search with those and similar terms, and I've added an example of what I found to my original post. I just don't completely know why the code does what it does so I don't know how to change it.

Comment: What do you do that you want automated? Do you want to keep a log of the prior versions, so that You'd specify "Smith" and the next version would be generated and logged, and then a week later another "Smith" or do you want to generate a batch of "Smiths" at once, but need to individually number the items in the batch with no on-going record?

Comment: With `/a-d` switch (=no directory) instead of `/ad` (=directories only): replace   last line `md "%baseName%%n%"` with `echo incremented "%baseName%n%"` to see result. Don't forget change `set "baseName=Smith "` (with a space before ending `"` quotation mark)

Comment: @Magoo:

What I'm doing is recording witnesses during video depositions. So what I'd like to do is start that day's job/task by entering in the witness' name (like Smith) and have the batch file use that name with incremented numbers for the .ISO filenames when I rip the DVDs. For the next job, I would run it again but this time enter in Jones and have the batch file do the same thing again.

I wouldn't need an on-going record beyond the particular job. Once I'm finished ripping the DVDs from Smith's deposition, I'm done with that and will then will do the same thing next time for Jones.

Comment: @JosefZ I added the modified code to my post. Did I make the correct changes? I added the pause so the window would stay open. After running the batch file, I get an output of `incremented "Smith n"`. Should this be checking for a file named Smith in the same directory the batch file is in?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "lastvideoname="

:loop
SET "videoname=%lastvideoname%"
SET /p "videoname=Enter Name [%videoname%] "
IF NOT DEFINED videoname GOTO :EOF
IF /i "%videoname%"=="quit" GOTO :EOF
IF /i "%videoname%" neq "%lastvideoname%" set /a volume=0
SET /a volume+=1
SET "lastvideoname=%videoname%"
ECHO now burning %videoname% volume %volume%
ECHO start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\ImgBurn\imgburn.exe /mode build /src D:\VIDEO_TS /dest "C:\Video\%videoname% %volume%.iso"
GOTO loop
```

Fairly simple. Ask for a new name, default to same name if <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is used. If the new name matches, increment the volume number, if not restart the volumne numbering.

Enter `quit` to peel potatoes.

Note that the `start` is simply `echo`ed for testing purposes. Remove the `echo` keyword to actually allow the `imgburn` process to proceed.

---

Revised version on supplemental information

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /p "videoname=Enter Name "
IF NOT DEFINED videoname GOTO :EOF

set /a volume=0
:loop
SET /a volume+=1

IF EXIST "C:\Video\%videoname% %volume%.iso" GOTO loop 
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\ImgBurn\imgburn.exe /mode build /src D:\VIDEO_TS /dest "C:\Video\%videoname% %volume%.iso"
GOTO :EOF
```

Simply build the destination name, if it already exists then increment the volume number until a unique name is found.

Note that these procedures rely on integrity of the input; that is, the entry made does not include any characters like `:|/\*?` etc. that cannot be used as part of a filename.

Comment: Nice! This is definitely on the right track. How would I have it look to a folder for an existing file of the same name instead of having it check its own loop? This would work except that I'm planning to have the batch file run when a DVD is inserted, so it would be reset each time instead of having the window open as I go from disc to disc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct file renaming script (commented using `rem`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
rem my testing command pushd "D:\bat\StackOverflow\files"
pushd "C:\Video"
if exist lastbaseName.txt (
  rem read last name saved
  for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (lastbaseName.txt) do set "baseName=%%~G"
) else (
  set "baseName=%username%"
)
if "%~1"=="" (
  set /p "baseName=Enter Name, Enter for default !baseName!: "
) else (
  set "baseName=%~1"
)
rem remember last name (or full history with >> redirector instead of > )
echo %baseName%>lastbaseName.txt
rem add a trailing space to basename end (optional)
set "baseName=%baseName% "
rem my testing command set "Extn=txt"
set "Extn=iso"
set /A "n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('
  2^>nul dir /b /a-d "%baseName%*.%Extn%"^
   ^|findstr /xri /c:"%baseName%[0-9]*.*"
') do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
  if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /a n+=1
set  "newName=%baseName%%n%.%Extn%"
echo %newName%
rem my testing command type nul>"%newName%"
echo start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\ImgBurn\imgburn.exe /mode build /src D:\VIDEO_TS /dest "C:\Video\%newName%"
popd
endlocal
```

Output:

```
d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28509860.bat
Smith 1.txt

d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28509860.bat
Smith 2.txt

d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28509860.bat
Smith 3.txt

d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28509860.bat Jones
Jones 1.txt

d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28509860.bat Jones
Jones 2.txt

d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28509860.bat
Smith 4.txt

d:\bat>
```

Comment: Ok, great. That works well to check for an existing file. Is there a way to have the batch retain the name I enter and have it use it for subsequent DVDs without prompting me each time I run the batch file? Could it use the last entered name for the rest of the day or until I reset it manually? I wonder if it can write what I enter into a text file and reference that if I don't enter something in 5 seconds.

Comment: I just thought of another way. I'm going to be having these write to a folder with the current date appended like this: C:\Video\video depo %datestamp%\  The batch file could reference the name of the first ISO in the folder for the current date and increment that. So, the batch file would look for an ISO in the folder or prompt for a name if it doesn't see one.

Comment: ad `21:18` comment: save last entered name to a file (`echo %baseName%>lastbaseName.txt`) and  instead of `set "baseName=%username%"`, read this file `for /F ... %%u ... do set "baseName=%%~u"`... ad `21:22` comment: overlaps original topic for the OQ

Comment: Note my time reference is `GMT+1` (this comment posted approx at `23:01` of my local time

Comment: I made those changes, but the batch doesn't seem to run if the `for /F ... %%u ... do set "baseName=%%~u"` string is entered instead of `set "baseName=%username%"`

If I add only `echo %baseName%>lastbaseName.txt`, the batch creates a text file with `ECHO is off.` as the body.

Comment: I put my current batch script in the original post.

Comment: Do not trust in code snippets validity, especially those in comments. The `...` ellipsis: [see 2nd denotation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ellipsis?s=t)  _a sequence of three dots (…) indicating an omission in text_. I beg your pardon I used _three full stops_ (`U+002E`) instead of   `…` character, Unicode `U+2026`, keystroke `Alt+0133`

Comment: So should I have it entered like this instead? `for /F %%u do set "baseName=%%~u"` Should `echo %baseName%>lastbaseName.txt` be added at the end of the entire batch file? Do I need to put `echo on` before this?